# Does lava evaporate in Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I just finished my lava moat, powered by a volcano. If I shut the lava supply, will the moat eventually dry up?

Comment: I hope it doesn't, because molten rock evaporating doesn't really make sense :)

Comment: @Badp - But this is Dwarf Fortress. DWARF. FORTRESS. Where, for a time, the humble Carp was the mightiest of enemies.

Comment: @badp: Well, water is just molten ice.

Comment: If I remember my physics from many years ago, water evaporates because it converts to vapour even at low temperatures and be suspended in air. I don't believe rock can do that in noticeable quantities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lava at 1/7 depth will eventually "evaporate", exactly the same as water. As long as your moat is a constant depth (even 2/7), your moat will remain, as is.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way of getting rid of my moat other than pumping up water?

Comment: I like to just pump it out, into an open area. If there's no way to renew the source, it'll eventually just all evaporate. This does lead some minor hazards to the brave pump operator though.